# How to pass a parameter through to a Rest Service in Xpages

Tags: rest, datagrid, xpages

[XPages Dojo Data Grid and Custom REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911574/xpages-dojo-data-grid-and-custom-rest-service/21026965#21026965)

*** Note: Mine is an XPINC application!
I've managed to get the above method working, but I want to pass a parameter through to the Rest Service in order to build a better return set.

In the above example it the script looks like this:

```
 <script>
   var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest(
     {target:"CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData"}
   ); 
   var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
 </script>
```

But, I want to do something like this:

```
 <script>
   var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest(
     {target:"CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData?OpenXpage&para1=Value1&para2=Value2"}
   ); 
   var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
 </script>
```

I've tried a number of methods, but no success.

Method 1 - Use Request/View/SessionScope variable
On the "CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp" I've added a "xp:this.beforePageLoad" event to create Scope variable to hold para1 and para2 taken from the paramValues of the URL.

I thought a simple requestScope would store them so I could pick them up when the "CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData" was called.  However, the Rest Service is called in the "onClientLoad" event of the page and the Scope variables don't seem to be available at this time.

Method 2 - Inline Javascript
I've also tried "${javascript:viewScope.para1;}" to pass it through:

```
 <script>
   var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest(
     {target:"CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData?OpenXpage&para1=${javascript:viewScope.para1;}&para2=${javascript:viewScope.para2;}"}
   ); 
   var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
 </script>
```

This didn't work.

Method 3 - Hardcoding
I have hardcoded the values.

```
 <script>
    var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest(
      {target:"CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData?OpenXpage&para1=Apples&para2=Oringes"}
    ); 
    var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
 </script>
```

This works! But, only for Apples & Oranges

I'm starting to look at using an Environment Variable to pass the values, but this just seems to be more of a hack than a solution.

Any help or guidance would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dan,

You may have a couple of things to check.

1. First thing is that you need to use # instead of $ to avoid
   evaluating the expression on page load
2. In some cases you cannot inject SSJS into the CSJS - if this is "evaluated" at page load time. You could be hitting this.... An easy
       way to check is to create a couple of local variables and assign the
       values from your SSJS. That'll make it easy to debug in the browser.

I guess you could do something like this (and then you can set a breakpoint in your browser and see if the values are as expected).

```
 <script>
   var p1 = "#{javascript:viewScope.para1;}";
   var p2 = "#{javascript:viewScope.para2;}";
   var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest(
     {target:"CURRENT_PAGE_NAME_HERE.xsp/gridData?OpenXpage&para1=" + p1 + "&para2=" + p2}
   ); 
   var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
 </script>
```

If this does not work then I suggest creating a script block in the beginning of your page with a simple little "getter" method for each variable (or the entire arg. string) and then use the SSJS there.

*Happy coding!*

*/John*

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for your help.  I'm going to play around with what you've suggested. I will need to look a little more closely and the difference between the "$" & "#".
I've just been cutting and pasting from the web to get this to work.  I haven't done much with Rest Services.
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an XPINC appplication, I felt it was safe to just use an Environment Variable.

On the view action button that calls the XPage, I write the Environment variable down onto the system. Then when I open the Xpage in the client, the Rest Service is hardwired to:

```
 var param1:String = session.getEnvironmentString("Param!");
```

I still think this feels more like a hack, but with Notes, I'm getting used to it. LOL

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was an XPinc app - I haven't got much experience with those. However, you need to understand the diference between '#' and '$' - your could would never have worked as shown with '$' for exactly that reason ;-)